# Freebase: User Domain: how to access /base/famouspets?

Tags: database, freebase

good morning,

I can't access the values of /base/famouspets in freebase. It's supposed to be a compound value.

For example, Britney Spears (http://www.freebase.com/m/05k72mf#/base/famouspets/pet_ownership)
has associated a pet. I know it from the links that says:

```
"id":"/base/famouspets/pet_owner/pets_owned",
"master_property":{"links":[{
  "source":{"id":"/m/05k72mf"},
  "target":"id":"/en/britney_spears"}]}
```

Here is the source property http://www.freebase.com/m/05k72mf but i can´t access the values. Does anybody know how to do this query to obtain the value "London" the name of the pet?

Comment: What I really would like to know is the name of the properties so I can ask for it's values. How do I do a query to ask for these properties: http://www.freebase.com/base/famouspets/pet_ownership

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there!  If you got to the page you linked to and click on "Build Query" (under the gear on the right side), it'll put you in the query editor with a basic query to which you can add the stuff that you're interested in.  The property names are listed on that page too (Pet, Owner, From, To).  The final query looks like [this](http://www.freebase.com/query?lang=/lang/en&q=%5B%7B%22id%22%3anull,%22name%22%3anull,%22type%22%3a%22/base/famouspets/pet_ownership%22,%22pet%22%3anull,%22owner%22%3a%5B%5D,%22from%22%3anull,%22to%22%3anull%7D%5D)

```
[{
  "id": null,
  "type": "/base/famouspets/pet_ownership",
  "pet": null,
  "owner": [],
  "from": null,
  "to": null
}]
```